Why does Bash alias named “l” fail but works if the alias name is changed to “lf?”
When I put this line in my .bash_aliases:
l() { pwd; ls -aoghs --author --color=always "$@"; echo `pwd` "$@"; }

I get this error:
bash: /root/.bash_aliases: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /root/.bash_aliases: line 4: `      l() { pwd; ls -aoghs --author --color=always "$@"; echo `pwd` "$@"; }'

If I change the name to ll it still fails. But lf works fine.  I've tried unset l at top but it doesn't help.
Any ideas?

Can't reproduce, works for me; that's a function, btw, not an alias.

unset is for variables, unalias is for aliases, unset -f is for functions

unset -v for variables, unset -f for functions, and unset for both variables and functions. Without options, unset looks at a variable and then a function and removes the one found first.

This happens when there is already an alias named l. Before your function definition l() { ...; } is evaluated, it is converted to something like ls -l() { ...; } (assuming the existing alias is alias l='ls -l'), which is a syntax error.

Solution 1: To avoid this type of problem, in Bash[Note 1], you can use the function definitions of the form function func { ...; } (where func is the function name). This fails only when there is an alias named function, so you only need to care about function instead of random alias names.
Solution 2: Or if you want to use the form func() { ...; }, you can always put unalias func before the function definition. It should be noted that unalias func needs to be put in a separate line because alias/unalias take the effect only from the next lines due to the nature of the Bash parser.


If I change the name to ll it still fails. But lf works fine.

That is because ll is also an alias in your environment but lf is not.

I've tried unset l at top but it doesn't help.

This is because unset l does not unset the alias. It removes a shell variable named l, and if not found, it removes a shell function named l. The unset builtin does not remove aliases. The unalias builtin can be used to remove aliases.


[Note 1]: Function definitions of the form function func { ...; }: Since this is .bash_aliases, one can assume the Bash features are available there. However, if you are going to write portable scripts (as specified by the POSIX standard) for a wide variety of shells such as ash/dash/BusyBox sh, {Free,Net,Open}BSD sh, etc. you'll need to use the form func() { ...; }. In shell scripts (instead of interactive settings), aliases are not usually defined by the environment, so you don't usually need to worry about aliases.


I wouldn't recommend the function func { ...; } form. It's nonstandard , and while it'll let you define a function with the same name as an alias, the alias will override the function, making it useless.

> It's nonstandard --- Yes, the form function func { ...; } should not be used in portable scripts (as defined by the POSIX standard). However, this question is about Bash, and .bash_aliases is anyway only for Bash.

> making it useless --- It doesn't necessarily. Aliases can be defined to repeat the same command name with additional command-line options. For example, alias mv='mv -i' and function e.g. mv() { do something extra; command mv "$@"; } may coexist so that both have effects.

@GordonDavisson I added a note. Could you check it?

Looks good to me.

@GordonDavisson Thank you.

Thanks everyone.  Unalias fixed my problem.
